# Solving Differential Equation Sympy

Tags: python-2.7, sympy

I haven't been able to find particular solutions to this differential equation.

```
from sympy import *

m = float(raw_input('Mass:\n> '))
g = 9.8
k = float(raw_input('Drag Coefficient:\n> '))
v = Function('v')
f1 = g * m
t = Symbol('t')
v = Function('v')
equation = dsolve(f1 - k * v(t) - m * Derivative(v(t)), 0)
print equation
```

for m = 1000 and k = .2 it returns

```
Eq(f(t), C1*exp(-0.0002*t) + 49000.0)
```

which is correct but I want the equation solved for when v(0) = 0 which should return

```
Eq(f(t), 49000*(1-exp(-0.0002*t))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Sympy is not yet able to take into account initial conditions. Although `dsolve` has the option `ics` for entering initial conditions (see the documentation), it appears to be of limited use.

Therefore, you need to apply the initial conditions manually. For example:

```
C1 = Symbol('C1')
C1_ic = solve(equation.rhs.subs({t:0}),C1)[0]

print equation.subs({C1:C1_ic})
```

> `Eq(v(t), 49000.0 - 49000.0*exp(-0.0002*t))`

Comment: This works well enough, are there any python packages that would do a better job of finding particular solutions to differential equations?

Comment: @JessieCotton I am not aware of any other python symbolic-math package than Sympy. However, I think the above methodology will be sufficient for most of the cases where the (general) solution of a diff. eq. can be found in closed form.

Comment: Initial conditions solving for this kind of ODE should be implemented in the next version of SymPy https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/11264

Comment: Is there a better way with sympy dsolve for this now? I am trying the `ics` argument but it does not seem to work.