# How to evaluate the constants SymPy gives with initial condition?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, sympy, differential-equations

How can I evaluate the constants C1 and C2 from a solution of a differential equation SymPy gives me? There are the initial condition f(0)=0 and f(pi/2)=3.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> f = Function('f')
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> dsolve(f(x).diff(x,2)+f(x),f(x))
f(x) == C1*sin(x) + C2*cos(x)
```

I tried some `ics` stuff but it's not working.  Example:

```
>>> dsolve(f(x).diff(x,2)+f(x),f(x), ics={f(0):0, f(pi/2):3})
f(x) == C1*sin(x) + C2*cos(x)
```

By the way: C2 = 0 and C1 = 3.

Comment: The `ics` argument in `dsolve`, although available, is not yet functional in the current Sympy version. You need to find the constants "manually" by solving the corresponding system of equation. This is a relatively simple task, e.g., see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950163/solving-differential-equation-sympy/38951359#38951359)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [pull request](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/11264) implementing initial/boundary conditions, which was merged and should be released in SymPy 1.2. Meanwhile, one can solve for constants like this:

```
sol = dsolve(f(x).diff(x,2)+f(x),f(x)).rhs
constants = solve([sol.subs(x,0), sol.subs(x, math.pi/2) - 3])
final_answer = sol.subs(constants)
```

The code returns `final_answer` as `3.0*sin(x)`.

#### Remarks

`solve` may return a list of solutions, in which case one would have to substitute `constants[0]`, etc. To force it to return a list in any case (for consistency), use `dict=True`:

```
constants = solve([sol.subs(x,0), sol.subs(x, math.pi/2) - 3], dict=True)
final_answer = sol.subs(constants[0])
```

If the equation contains parameters, `solve` may or may not solve for the variables you want (C1 and C2). This can be ensured as follows:

```
constants = solve([sol.subs(x,0), sol.subs(x, math.pi/2) - 3], symbols('C1 C2'))
```

where  again, `dict=True` would force the list format of  the output.

Comment: In this case, the only free variables in `[sol.subs(x,0), sol.subs(x, math.pi/2) - 3]` are `C1` and `C2`, so one can see why `solve` solves for them, but I've seen that `solve` Does The Right Thing even when there are other free variables in the equations of initial/boundary conditions... Neat!  On the other hand, I've  spent some time trying to tell `solve` that I wanted said equations solved with respect to variables that I couldn't name... until I found your answer, that is.

Comment: I've found that the Python type (a `dict` inside a `list` vs a bare `dict`) of the solution returned by `solve` depends on letting `sympy` choose the variables to solve for (`dict` in `list`) rather than passing a tuple of  symbols (bare `dict`). Of course using `dict=True` is a good workaround... A final remark: `dict=True` is documented clearly but the name, isn't the name a bit misleading?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Regarding the pull request behavior that is now in the git master version of SymPy: the flag is called `ics` but it will work for any set of conditions that produce a unique solution for the constants through `solve`. So it should work for boundary conditions, assuming solve can handle the given equations.