# Cannot substitute the constants of integration into the integral of response

Tags: sympy

Let's use `sympy` to find the response of a linear system to an external force

```
from sympy import *

t, w, beta = symbols('t omega beta', positive=1)
x0, v0 = symbols('x0 v0')
x = symbols('x', cls=Function)
homogeneous = diff(x(t), t, 2)/w**2+x(t)
force = sin(beta*w*t)
disp = dsolve(homogeneous-force, x(t)).rhs
display(disp)
constants = solve((disp.subs(t,0)-x0, disp.diff(t).subs(t,0)-v0))
display(constants)
```

obtaining

```
                                    sin(beta*omega*t)
C1*sin(omega*t) + C2*cos(omega*t) - -----------------
                                            2        
                                        beta  - 1    
          2                               
      beta *v0 + beta*omega - v0          
[{C1: --------------------------, C2: x0}]
                /    2    \               
          omega*\beta  - 1/
```

Now, to complete my solution, I tried to substitute these constant of integration into the general+particular integral

```
display(disp.subs(constants))
```

that gives me

```
                                    sin(beta*omega*t)
C2*sin(omega*t) + C2*cos(omega*t) - -----------------
                                            2        
                                        beta  - 1
```

Where have I done a mistake?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @jmoon — In the second block of code, I expect to see, in place of `C1` and `C2`, the symbolic values that I have computed and displayed at the end of the first block of code, because I've asked `sympy` to operate such a substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument of `subs` should be a dictionary.

What you got from `solve` as `constants` is not a dictionary but a one-element list containing a dictionary. Use it as

```
disp.subs(constants[0])
```

then the result is

```
x0*cos(omega*t) - sin(beta*omega*t)/(beta**2 - 1) + (beta**2*v0 + beta*omega - v0)*sin(omega*t)/(omega*(beta**2 - 1))
```

Comment: Oops, I'd know it better...  I have to say that I was partly misled by [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41193705/2749397) that I've previously found . Thanks a lot for both answers.