# Sympy plot: plotting a function with multiple free variables (python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, sympy

Firstly, can I plot something that I have declared as function? Because I'm getting loads of errors but it doesn't show where in my code the error is coming from e.g.:

```
import sympy as sy

rho = 1000 # Density of water [kg/m3]
A = 1.0 # Cross-sectional area of tank [m2]
c = 50 # Valve constant [kg/s per opening percent]
o = 100 # Percent valve opening 

h = sy.Function('h')
t = sy.symbols('t')

m_bal = sy.Eq(h(t).diff(t),c/(rho*A)*o)
gen_sol = sy.dsolve(m_bal,h(t))
C = gen_sol.subs([(t,0),(h(0),0)])
sol = gen_sol.subs([(C.rhs,C.lhs)])
sy.plot(t,h)
```

Then I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-7aa8880d452a> in <module>()
     14 C = gen_sol.subs([(t,0),(h(0),0)])
     15 sol = gen_sol.subs([(C.rhs,C.lhs)])
---> 16 sy.plot(t,h)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\plot.py in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   1288     show = kwargs.pop('show', True)
   1289     series = []
-> 1290     plot_expr = check_arguments(args, 1, 1)
   1291     series = [LineOver1DRangeSeries(*arg, **kwargs) for arg in plot_expr]
   1292 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\plot.py in check_arguments(args, expr_len, nb_of_free_symbols)
   1791 
   1792         exprs = args[:i]
-> 1793         assert all(isinstance(e, Expr) for expr in exprs for e in expr)
   1794         free_symbols = list(set().union(*[e.free_symbols for expr in exprs
   1795                                         for e in expr]))

AssertionError:
```

Secondly, I want to plot that for `t = 0`s to `t = 10`s and I only want `o = 100` for `t = [2,7]`. I have done this but I don't know where I'm going wrong:

```
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing()

rho = 1000 # Density of water [kg/m3]
A = 1.0 # Cross-sectional area of tank [m2]
c = 50 # Valve constant [kg/s per opening percent]
o = 100

h = sy.Function('h')
t = sy.symbols('t')

m_bal = sy.Eq(h(t).diff(t),c/(rho*A)*o)
gen_sol = sy.dsolve(m_bal,h(t))
C = gen_sol.subs([(t,0),(h(0),0)])
sol = gen_sol.subs([(C.rhs,C.lhs)])
sy.plot(t,h)
```

Can I do this on sympy or do I have to use matplotlib and numpy and do:

```
o= np.zeros(100) # % Valve opening 
o[21:70] = 100 # % opening at times 2s to 7s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sy.plot(t, h)` is problematic for multiple reasons. First, in SymPy's `plot` the function comes before the variable: for example, `sy.plot(t**2, (t, 0, 3))`.

Second, nothing you did with the ODE had any impact on `t` or `h`. You are just trying to plot something with `sy.Function('h')` with no indication of what `h` is. SymPy objects do not mutate; unless you assign something to `h`, it's not going to change.

The attempt to enforce the initial condition also looks strange. In the current version of SymPy (1.2) the initial conditions can be imposed by `dsolve` itself. This is how I would solve and plot the solution:

```
sol = sy.dsolve(m_bal, h(t), ics={h(0): 0})
sy.plot(sol.rhs, (t, 0, 3))
```

Comment: When I use ics={} and then print the solution, the integration constant is still not replaced by a value. But when I plot it, it takes the initial condition into account. How can I replace that constant?
And thanks for your help btw

Comment: That's why I wrote "In the current version of SymPy (1.2)". In an older version such as yours, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192748/