# Solved ODE by Sympy doesn't satisfy the given initial condition

Tags: sympy, ode

I'm trying to solve the following simple ODE using `dsolve` function in Sympy

```
v = sp.Function('v', real=True)
t, g, m, c = sp.symbols('t g m c', positive=True, real=True)
eq = sp.Eq(v(t).diff(t), g - c/m*v(t)**2)
sol = sp.dsolve(eq, v(t), ics={v(0):0})
```

The result isn't as simple as expected but the strange point is that if you check the solution to insure that the given initial condition is satisfied, it doesn't return the correct result (`v(0)=0`), as passed in the `dsolve` by `ics` argument.

```
sol.subs(t,0)
```

Comment: What version of sympy do you use, `print(sympy.__version__)`? Does the documentation in your version give a guarantee that the ics argument will be used in the solution? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192748/how-to-evaluate-the-constants-sympy and related.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann, thanks you your attention. I'm using the lastest version. The `ics` argument is fully functional now.

Comment: Looks like a sympy error. It fails to replace the compound constant with a new one. Also it simplifies too early to 1/tanh, which prevent a sensible expression at time zero. The given solution could still be correct if one abuses the complex logarithm, which however should not be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Replacing `u=c/m*v` and `c/m*g=a^2` one gets the equation `u'=a^2-u^2` which is separable and leads to

```
log|u+a|-log|u-a| = 2*a*t+c
```

This should be transformed to

```
(u+a)/(u-a) = C*exp(2*a*t)

u = a*(C*exp(2*a*t)+1)/(C*exp(2*a*t)-1)
```

where then the initial condition leads to `C=-1` and `u(t)=a*tanh(a*t)`.

As the constant in the sympy solution is apparently not removed from the exponent, and the resolution of the absolute value towards a negative sign also apparently not followed, sympy ends up with a variation of `c=log(-1)/2`, which makes no sense in this context of an equation over the reals. Also `-1` is on the usual branch cut of the complex logarithm, making this even more uncertain. In the actual solution one finds `log((-1)**sqrt(m))` which is not a well-defined expression.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `dsolve` finds the general solution:

```
In [41]: sol
Out[41]: 
                      √g⋅√m               
v(t) = ───────────────────────────────────
              ⎛             ⎛ C₁⋅√c⋅√g⋅m⎞⎞
              ⎜          log⎝ℯ          ⎠⎟
              ⎜√c⋅√g⋅t - ────────────────⎟
              ⎜                 2        ⎟
       √c⋅tanh⎜──────────────────────────⎟
              ⎝            √m            ⎠
```

Before attempting to solve for `C1` here it would be better to apply some constant simplification:

```
In [42]: [logterm] = sol.atoms(log)

In [43]: C1 = Symbol('C1')

In [44]: sol2 = sol.subs(logterm, C1)

In [45]: sol2
Out[45]: 
                √g⋅√m         
v(t) = ───────────────────────
              ⎛  C₁          ⎞
              ⎜- ── + √c⋅√g⋅t⎟
              ⎜  2           ⎟
       √c⋅tanh⎜──────────────⎟
              ⎝      √m      ⎠

In [46]: [c] = solve(sol2.rhs.subs(t, 0), C1)

In [47]: c
Out[47]: ⅈ⋅π⋅√m

In [48]: sol2.subs(C1, c)
Out[48]: 
                 √g⋅√m          
v(t) = ─────────────────────────
              ⎛          ⅈ⋅π⋅√m⎞
              ⎜√c⋅√g⋅t - ──────⎟
              ⎜            2   ⎟
       √c⋅tanh⎜────────────────⎟
              ⎝       √m       ⎠

In [49]: sol2.subs(C1, c).simplify()
Out[49]: 
                 ⎛√c⋅√g⋅t⎞
       √g⋅√m⋅tanh⎜───────⎟
                 ⎝   √m  ⎠
v(t) = ───────────────────
                √c
```

Perhaps actually it is better to solve for the constant at an earlier stage in the solving process. Probably on pen and paper it would make sense to solve for the constant as soon as integration happens and while the equation is still in implicit form.