# SymPy returns wrong solution of a nonlinear ODE?

Tags: python, sympy, ode, solver

I am trying to solve the ODE of the frictional free fall:

```
from sympy import *
t = symbols ('t')
v = Function ('v')
dgl = Eq (diff (v(t), t) + v(t)**2, 1)
```

[image]

```
erg = dsolve (dgl)
```

[image]

I think the solution might be wrong. I believe it should be the reciprocal of the returned expression. Therefore, if I try to find the value of the constant for an initial condition of rest (v(0) = 0), I get no real solutions:

```
C1 = symbols ('C1')
solve (erg.rhs.subs (t, 0), C1)
```

[image]

As a consequence, if I ask SymPy to solve the ODE with the initial condition, it throws errors:

```
dsolve (dgl, ics = {v(0): 0})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sympy answer is formally correct, with `v=u'/u` one gets `u''=u` so that

```
u(t) = A*exp(t)+B*exp(-t)

v(t) = (A*exp(t)-B*exp(-t))/(A*exp(t)+B*exp(-t))
```

Depending on how the constants are combined into one parameter, and what sign combination one prefers, one has

```
A = D*exp(-C), B = D*exp(C) ==> v(t) = tanh(t-C)

A = D*exp(-C), B =-D*exp(C) ==> v(t) = ctgh(t-C)
```

One can switch from one version to the other using complex factors, as the solver did

```
ctgh(t-C+i*pi/2) = (i*exp(t-C)+(-i)*exp(-t+C))/(i*exp(t-C)-(-i)*exp(-t+C))

                 = tanh(t-C)
```

This is what the solver for the initial condition proposed.

---

What you can do is check what other solution paths are available

```
classify_ode(dgl)
#('separable',
# '1st_exact',
# '1st_rational_riccati',
# '1st_power_series',
# 'lie_group',
# 'separable_Integral',
# '1st_exact_Integral')

dsolve (dgl, ics = {v(0): 0}, hint='1st_rational_riccati')
# Eq(v(t), (1 - exp(2*t))/(-exp(2*t) - 1))
dsolve (dgl, ics = {v(0): 0}, hint='1st_rational_riccati').simplify()
# Eq(v(t), tanh(t))
```

which gives a sensible solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, Lutz. That was extremely helpful! Is there a way to ask the solver to automatically try different solution paths until it finds a path that does not run into an error?

Comment: I tried to apply your approach to the real world by adding mass, friction, and gravitational acceleration:
`m, k, g = symbols ('m k g', positive = True);
dgl = Eq (m * diff (v(t), t) + k * v(t)**2, m * g)`
Unfortunately, all offered hints either return errors or complex solutions which I could not (trig)simplify to the expected solution:

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=m+*+dv%28t%29%2Fdt+%2B+k+*+v%28t%29**2+%3D+m+*+g%2C+v%280%29+%3D+0)

Comment: Yes, that situation was already discussed once here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68901115/solved-ode-by-sympy-doesnt-satisfy-the-given-initial-condition. Apparently the solver philosophy is to keep the constant in the exponent, as shift of the independent variable, which gives overly complicated expressions when initial values are given. Especially if to reach them one has to use complex-valued constants that might give a periodic solution set all for the same real solution.

Comment: As from your own experience: Is there hope that SymPy will return the "real" solution in the near future? Did you or @Oscar Benjamin launch a bug report / feature request a year ago?

Comment: There is a related error report https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19183 where  [bigfooted commented on 26 Apr 2020](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19183#issuecomment-619619592) describes the correct approach to the general Riccati equation that would also help here. In principle this is implemented in the `'1st_rational_riccati'` path, so this seems to be a classification problem. The problem seems to be `m` as leading coefficient, somehow the `positive` property is not enough to ensure that no division by zero occurs.

Comment: Even if we add a `nonzero` assumption: `m, k, g = symbols ('m k g', positive = True, nonzero = True)`, `classify_ode (dgl)` does not offer `1st_rational_riccati`: `('factorable',  'separable', '1st_exact', '1st_power_series', 'lie_group', 'separable_Integral', '1st_exact_Integral')`

Comment: I did not explore the details in riccati.py, but it seems that something goes wrong with the type normalization when bringing the Riccati equation to normal form `y'=b0+b1*y+b2*y^2`.